# Vagrant error: The provider 'aws' could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant

I am using Vagrant 1.6.5 and trying to deploy to Amazon AWS.  I can successfully deploy to DigitalOcean, but with AWS I get the error:

```
The provider 'aws' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that  
exists.
```

I have verified that the aws plugin is installed, with

```
$ vagrant plugin list
vagrant-aws (0.5.0)
vagrant-digitalocean (0.7.0)
vagrant-login (1.0.1, system)
vagrant-share (1.1.1, system)
```

When I google for this error, the only advice I get is to add

```
vagrant.require_plugin 'vagrant-aws'
```

to the start of the Vagrantfile.  However this does not fix the error, and vagrant says it is deprecated anyway.

I am really stuck on this, and I don't know what to do next. Below is the full error message, in case it is useful.

Thank you,
Jason

```
ERROR vagrant: Vagrant experienced an error! Details:
ERROR vagrant: #<Vagrant::Errors::ProviderNotFound: The provider 'aws' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.>
ERROR vagrant: The provider 'aws' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.
ERROR vagrant: /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:119:in `machine_config'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:45:in `machine'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:537:in `machine'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:168:in `block in with_target_vms'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:192:in `call'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:192:in `block in with_target_vms'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:174:in `each'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:174:in `with_target_vms'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:67:in `block in execute'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in batch'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:266:in `tap'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:266:in `block in batch'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:265:in `synchronize'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:265:in `batch'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:58:in `execute'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:292:in `cli'
/opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/bin/vagrant:174:in `<main>'
 INFO interface: error: The provider 'aws' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.
The provider 'aws' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.
 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::ProviderNotFound", "The provider 'aws' could not be found, but was requested to\nback the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists."]
```

Comment: Could you share your vagrantfile or link to a gist with it?

Comment: Nevermind!  I just uninstalled the vagrant-aws plugin and reinstalled it, and now it works.  There must have been something wrong with the first installation, I guess.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 9):

Here is the solution, in case somebody searches for this.  I uninstalled the vagrant-aws plugin, and reinstalled:

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-aws
vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
```

This fixed the problem.